# Prevent keyboard to appear with a textfield as a first responder

Tags: ios, keyboard-events, uikeyboard

I do a new post because I have a problem that I can't find the respons on the internet. I'm working with a bluetooth barcoder  with a clean view without any viewable textfields. To catch the information of the barcoder I use a hidden textfield and works fine. The problem is when the Barcoder disconnects it appears the keyboard because a field is the first responder. I don't want to resign that field but I don't want the keyboard appears.

I have a function that catch when the keyboard will appear:

`[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                        selector:@selector (keyboardWillShow:)
                                         name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];`

What I want is to stop the event of the keyboard or if not's possible hide it when appears. Any ideas about it? Any help will very usefull...

Thanks guys!

Comment: It's solved! I have made an blank input view so no keyboard appears:

' [_textSender setInputView:[[UIView alloc] init]];'

I hope it help to someone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dhilip's answer may work for you. If it doesn't here are some alternatives:

1) set the textField.enabled property to NO.

2) Subclass UITextField and return nil for the inputView:

```
@interface MyTextField: UITextField

@end

@implementation MyTextField

- (void)inputView
{
    return nil;
}

@end
```

If you use your custom textfield class instead of a regular UITextField, it works the same except that you've said to use nil for it's keyboard instead of UIKeyboardView (which is the default).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot understand your question properly, but still i got a suggestion for you.

If you are setting the text in UITextField programmatically, you can set userInteractionEnabled property to No.